# How make a slight modification on X_test from (57,) to (57, 1)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have datasets that have more than 2000 rows and 23 columns including the age column. I have completed all of the processes for SVR. Now I am preparing my code for training and test set which includes the rows until row number 1000. My code runs well. As my `output` for `X_test is (57, ).` Now, I need to make a slight modification on X_test because its shape is `(57,)`. I need to change it to some variable that is of shape `(57,1)`. I may either convert it into a pandas dataframe or numpy array. But How may I do this? I am a beginner for this work. Please may help to write this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make fake dataset
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(2000,22))
dataset['age'] = np.random.randint(2, size=2000)

# Separate the target from the other features
target = dataset['age']
data = dataset.drop('age', axis = 1)

# train_data, train_target = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000] - alternate naming scheme
X_train, y_train = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000]

# test_data, test_target = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001] - alternate naming scheme
X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001]
```

Output for X_test: `(57, )`

Comment: @HS-nebula Please may help me to solve this. Thank You

Comment: @Bobs-Burgers Please may help me to solve this. Thank You

Comment: Use double bracket: `X_test, y_test = data.loc[[1001]], target.loc[[1001]]`

Comment: It shows the output (1, 57) and also shows an error that is:  `KeyError: 0`

Comment: Are you sure you want `(57,1)`? Your `X_train` is `(1000, 57)`, shouldn't `X_test` be `(1,57)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My X_train is (977, 57).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `reshape` : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

```py
X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape((len(X_test), 1))
print(X_test.shape)
```

Comment: It still shows only (57, ). How can I reshape it by (57, 1)?

Comment: Had to update the solution. It was len(X_test) not X_test[0] sorry. Hope it works now!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very kind of You. It is working pretty well.

Comment: Is it possible to prediction on the trained SVR model? I need to input "X_test" to the model??